# What technology is used to serve HTTP requests compatible with Python

Tags: python, apache, http

I'm building an application on AWS and well, this world is new to me.

I expose the problem

I have experience with Apache / PHP, Apache is the one who helps me serve HTTP requests and PHP is the language of Backend.

The backend language that I am using in this new project is Python, but my question is, what is the technology that helps me serve the requests?

Can I install Apache / Python, or what would be the perfect duo?

I know this can have many variants depending on each experience and needs of the project, but honestly I am lost in what to install and what not.

Thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best course of action if just learning how to do web programming in Python is to not worry about how you host it. Start out with one of the major Python web frameworks and work through their tutorials. The best options are:

- Flask - http://flask.pocoo.org/
- Django - https://www.djangoproject.com/

They will explain the basics of building your web application. They use a development server to host your application. Only once you understand programming basics, then worry about a production grade web server.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to look at uWSGI:

- https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WebServers.html

mod_wsgi for Apache:

- https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

For simple pages you still have CGI:

- https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/cgi.html

There exists also mod_python for Apache, but it isn't modern way to embed Python interpreter within the webserver **(don't use it, here only for information purposes!)**.

- http://modpython.org/

Comment: You should not use mod_python. The solution for Apache is now mod_wsgi.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks, added emphasis to not use it in answer.